# Good PayPal library for CodeIgniter, anyone?

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I am looking for a good PayPal library to use in CodeIgniter. I used to hardcode it, but now I'm rewriting my web app and I have decided to use a good PayPal library class instead of writing my own.

I don't have PayPal Payments Pro that's why I can't use [CodeIgniter Payments](http://getsparks.org/packages/codeigniter-payments/versions/HEAD/show).

Answer (score 4):

You may try:

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/PayPal_Lib

Comment: Hi Usman. I've checked this out before but I'm not very comfortable on using it since it lacks a good documentation (and the link to the 'more extensive' documentation is already dead). But thanks for the tip, if I can't find another one I'll try to make do of this.

Comment: Go with Usman's suggestion!  Not sure of the documentation but dive into the code...not alot to diguest